# Android - sequential/nested dialog boxes, second dialog box closes the first one

Tags: android, dialog, numberpicker

I have an application that when a button is pressed, a dialog box containing a list will appear and after selecting a certain item in the list, a number picker dialog then appears. What I want to happen is that after the user selects a number from the number picker dialog, **only the number picker dialog will close, leaving the dialog box still up**.

This is my code so far.

This is the code for the first dialog box (the one with the list):

```
private void generateUnitDialog(String[] productUnit) {

    final CharSequence[] items = productUnit;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Make your selection");

    builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // Handle Confirm action here
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // Handle cancel action here
        }
    });
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            // Do something with the selection
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Item Click detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            generateQuantityDialog();

        }
    });

    builder.setCancelable(false);

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

When a certain list item is selected, the numberpicker dialog then pops up using this code:

```
public int generateQuantityDialog(){

         final Dialog d = new Dialog(com.angelo.orderform.OrderForm.this);

         d.setTitle("Choose Quantity");
         d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

         Button b1 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
         Button b2 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button2);

         final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);

         np.setMaxValue(100000);
         np.setMinValue(1);
         np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
         //np.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

         b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 //tv.setText(String.valueOf(np.getValue()));
                 d.dismiss();
             }    
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              d.dismiss();
           }    
          });
       d.show();

       return(np.getValue());


}
```

After the user selects a certain number, the number picker dialog closes as well as the one with the list. I want the dialog with the list to stay on.

Apparently, setCancellable(false) does not help.

Any ideas? Even if it's a different approach, I'm open ears.

Comment: can you get my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out but I think it's bad practice.

What I did was I placed the code that generates the number picker dialog and placed it to where `generateQuantityDialog()` originally was and just called `builder.show()` after `d.dismiss()`.

I'll look for a work around, ditching this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 Dialog d;
  AlertDialog.Builder builder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      final CharSequence[] items = {"a","b","c"};

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Make your selection");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Handle Confirm action here
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Handle cancel action here
            }
        });
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                // Do something with the selection
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Item Click detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                generateQuantityDialog();

            }
        });

        builder.setCancelable(false);

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

public int generateQuantityDialog(){

     d = new Dialog(this);

    d.setTitle("Choose Quantity");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.al);

    Button b1 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button b2 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button2);

   //        final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

   //        np.setMaxValue(100000); 
   //        np.setMinValue(1);
        //        np.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    //np.setOnValueChangedListener(this);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //tv.setText(String.valueOf(np.getValue()));
            d.dismiss();
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

        }


   });
   b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         d.dismiss();
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

     }


     });
  d.show();

  return(54);


  }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry I don't see how this is different from what I have.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `AlertDialog alert` variable **global**.

as per your require you can cancel or dismiss `alertdialog`.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 //tv.setText(String.valueOf(np.getValue()));
                 d.dismiss();
                 alert.dismiss() ; or 
                 alert.cancel();
             }    
        });
```

You can dismiss alertDialog as per your requirement.

like if select second dialog.

Comment: This one is confusing. I want the first dialog (alert dialog) to stay AFTER the numberpicker has executed. The onClickListener you have there dismiesses the number picker AND the alert dialog, which is not what I want to do.